# How to use Ember.Select in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have posted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/XQbqU/).

I am new to ember.js and still in learning phase.Here i am trying to build simple CRUD program.

I am trying to use select in above CRUD program using Ember.Select but i am not able to use it.

```
      {{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding="Objtype.content"
        valueBinding="Objtype.selected"
        prompt="Please select a type"
        }}
```

How to use ember.select in above CRUD program to create/update record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
Objtype: Ember.Object.create({
  selected: null,
  content: ['1', 2]
})
```

to this:

```
objtype: Ember.Object.create({
  selected: null,
  content: ['1', 2]
})
```

you should notice I changed 'O' for 'o', and you also need to update your select to use the right property name